# auto scale azure cloud service by memory

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-cloud-services

Does anyone know how to scale an azure cloud service by memory/RAM usage?I have a medium VM and the cpu barely goes over 20% but the memory (when load testing etc) gets pretty high. I can see how to do it for webapps but not cloud services. Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: How did you solve this, in the end?

Comment: Couldnt do it at the time unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot scale a cloud service by memory usage.

You can only scale by CPU usage or by queue length. (or a combination of both using the Service Management REST API - Info on autoscale: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn510374.aspx)

Comment: [This documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/best-practices-auto-scaling/) says that "Azure Autoscale supports the most common scaling scenarios based on a schedule and, optionally, triggered scaling operations based on runtime metrics (such as processor utilization, queue length, or built-in and **custom counters**)..."